# how to retrieve json data from pouchdb

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

im trying to return a particular Json data from **pouchdb** and if the data exists i want to display it some activity. But somehow im not able to do so. 
*my code*

```
var PouchDB = require('PouchDB'); 
//Creating the database object 
var db = new PouchDB('my_database');
 //Reading the contents of a Document 
var res = db.get('001', function(err, doc)
  if (err)
 {
 return console.log(err);
 } 
else
 { 
var data = JSON.stringify(res)
return console.log(doc);
 } });
```

The result i get is :{}
emptyset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example is that you are using PouchDB with callbacks and Promises. You need to either use the callback or the promise. Here's the snippet that you should use. I made an example with callbacks and promises.

Promises make your workflow way cleaner as you can see.

Also, the example won't run directly in StackOverflow due to security reasons. Here's an external working example: http://jsbin.com/javipoguqe/1/edit?js,console

```js
//Creating the database object 
var db = new PouchDB('my_database');

//Callback example 

db.get('001', function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  } else {
    var data = JSON.stringify(res)
    return console.log(doc);
  }
});

//Promise example

var promise = db.get('001');
promise.then(function(res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});


//Example to show advantages of promises

db.put({
  '_id': "001",
  name: "newdoc"
}).then(function(res) {
  return db.get('001');
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log("Document was added and retrieved");
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/latest/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```